# Different Comment Box on each Website Page

Tags: facebook, comments

I have a website with about 60 different pages written in simple HTML.  I want people to be able to comment on each page separately without comments from one page showing up on another page.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use the Facebook comments box ? If yes then you just need to change the data-href value.

Example:-

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mywebsite.com/page-first.html" data-num-posts="10" data-width="470"></div>
```

here is url  to create a facebook comment box.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/